# why is ma json data read on PC but not in android?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to save the name of the last level my player gets in and I wanted to use Json and the streaming assets folder, so I get a JSON file in a folder in my unity project

```
└───Assets
    └───[...] (all my other unity project folder)
    └───StreamingAssets
            lastlevel.json
```

I created an  object ProgressSavior with and attached script to save in this JSON file the name of the level and also add a function to get the level name, so that in my main menu when I press **play** my last scene played is loaded

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ProgressSavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    string chemin = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/lastlevel.json";
    Regex levelRegex = new Regex(@"^level_[1-9][0-9]*$");
    string Json;
    string levelname;
    Level Saved;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        levelname = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
        Json = File.ReadAllText(chemin);
        Saved = JsonUtility.FromJson<Level>(Json);
        if (levelRegex.IsMatch(levelname)) {
            save();
        }
    }
    bool ShouldWeSave(string s)
    {
        Debug.Log(s);
        Debug.Log(Saved.name);
        return int.Parse(s.Split('_')[1]) > int.Parse(Saved.name.Split('_')[1]);
    }

    public void save()
    {

        if (ShouldWeSave(levelname))
        {
            Saved.name = levelname;
            Json = JsonUtility.ToJson(Saved);
            File.WriteAllText(chemin, Json);
        } else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("saving was Useless");
        }
    }

    public string load()
    {
        return Saved.name;
    }

}

public class Level
{
    public string name;
}
```

And on PC it work wonderfully but when I build the project on android it won't work and I don't understand why,

Comment: Are you sure the File is null? I think File Path is correct and you have a problem in Content.
Just write a simple code to read and write a plain text to your path, just to check the path or parser problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, the path will be different, as mentioned in the official documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html).

Use `"jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets"` instead.

Comment: I tried this but I still have an issue on my android device: `DirectoryNotFoundException: could not find a part of the path "/jar:file:/data/app/com.DefaultCompany.[myappname]-oXV3gDa1EG5BHo_pjF2SZA==/base.apk!/assests/lastlevel.json`

Comment: isn't it another folder I could use like data ressource or so ?